# mongoDB update with arrayFilters not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following doc structure (simplified) in mongo:

```
{
  "_id":"5e30208675b5400cb0894c52",
  "locations": [
    {
      "name": "Pleasure Gardens",
      "id": 618,
      "areas": [
        {
          "name": "Koi Pond",
          "area_id": 159,
          "is_active": true,
        },
        ...other areas
      ],
      ...other locations 
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to set the **is_active** field in the areas array to false where the id of the location is 618 and the the area_id of the area is 159.

I'm doing the following:

```
const db = await connectDb();

return await db
 .collection('test')
 .updateOne(
   {"locations.areas.area_id": 159},
   { $set: {"locations.$[l].areas.$[a].is_active": false }},
   { arrayFilters: [{ "l.id": 618 }, { "a.area_id": 159 }] }
);
```

But I'm getting:

```
MongoError: cannot use the part (locations of locations.$[l].areas.$[a].is_active) to traverse the element
```

I've checked other responses and as far as I can tell the syntax is correct and I'm also using a mongodb version that supports the arrayFilters method ("mongodb": "^3.6.3") in nodejs, so why is it being so cruel to me? WHYYYY?!?!

**UPDATE**

After reading through the comments I realised that although I have version 3.6.3 of the mongodb npm package installed, the version of the database itself is actually 3.0.14

This means that the arrayFilters method is not supported and I will probably have to take a 2 step approach to solve this problem:

1. query mongodb to find the document:

- store result in a variable
- update the variable in the code itself with (change is_active to false)

2. use an update query to substitute the whole document in mongo with the document stored in variable (rather than just updating the desired area)

Comment: Are you sure you are on the right database?

Comment: Can you try change command?

.updateOne(
   {"locations.areas.area_id": 159},
   { $set: {"locations.$[l].areas.$.is_active": false }},
   { arrayFilters: [{ "l.id": 618 }] }
);

Comment: Maybe provide the following details so we confirm the correct version is in place: db.version() ; db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } );

Comment: @ŠtěpánZechner tested on mongodb 3.6.3, nodeJS native drive and it works (updates the document). No errors if in the wrong database neither. So it may be something else. Maybe the code itself...

Comment: @Minsky I think you are right, I checked the database and the version is 3.0.14 and this version does not support the arrayFilters method :(

Comment: Uhm..I'll check for an alternative way. I think you should do it on the application side, Bring elements with `{"locations.areas.area_id": 159}` and run for loops. Then update those, surely this is risky, but can't see any alternative.

Comment: @Minsky Yes, that is exactly what I did. Brought the elements and then used loops to update in application and the second query to update the database. Not great but it works

Answer (score 0):

For me is working correctly(mongod/mongos version 4.4.3):

```
mongos> db.l.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : "5e30208675b5400cb0894c52",
"locations" : [
    {
        "name" : "Pleasure Gardens",
        "id" : 618,
        "areas" : [
            {
                "name" : "Koi Pond",
                "area_id" : 159,
                "is_active" : true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

```
 mongos> db.l.updateOne( {"locations.areas.area_id": 159} , { $set:{"locations.$[loc].areas.$[are].is_active":false }}, { arrayFilters: [{ "loc.id": 618 }, { "are.area_id": 159 }] }     )
// { "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }

mongos> db.l.find({ "locations.areas.area_id": 159  } ,{"locations.areas.is_active":1  })
// { "_id" : "5e30208675b5400cb0894c52", "locations" : [ { "areas" : [ { "is_active" : false } ] } ] }
```

Comment: mate this doesn't solve the question or maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @Minsky: successful test details difficult to post as comment so posted as answer ... ( just attempting to help the man in trouble  ...)