# Mongoose update in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to update the quantity of the product, but it always inserts a new product to the inputBuffer instead of updating. How can I do a real updating?

```
[
  {
    "_id": "61ae51f22e8fe709d477f19d",
    "name": "ALINE-1",
    "steps": [
      {
        "_id": "61ae51f22e8fe709d477f19e",
        "inputBuffer": [
          {
            "prodQuantity": 5,
            "_id": "61ae52012e8fe709d477f1a0",
            "prodName": "cogs"
          }
        ],
        "outputBuffer": []
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

and the code:

```
const updateProductInInputBuffer = ({ assemblyLineName, steps, prodName, prodQuantity }) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const filter = ({ name: assemblyLineName });
    AssemblyLine.findOneAndUpdate(filter, {
      $set: {
        [`steps.${steps - 1}.inputBuffer.$[p].prodQuantity`]: prodQuantity
      }
    }, {
      new: true,
      arrayFilters: [
        {
          'p.prodName': prodName
        }
      ]
    }).then((documents) => {
      resolve(documents);
    }).catch((err) => {
      logger.info('updating error');
      reject(err);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Here is a similar SO post with an update on a nested array field (two levels of nesting) using `arrayFilters` update option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65619601/mongodb-update-with-arrayfilters-not-working

Comment: It was my fault. My code is works well, just I forgot to change in the swagger from 'post' to 'put'