# $set { "array.index.value" :"newvalue"} use something instead of index or use variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am using mongoose to store user data, and one of the attributes is items: []
in my additems.js:

```js
const User = require('../models/User');
var array = user.items
        array.indexOfObject = function (property, value) {
            for (let i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
              if (this[i][property] === value) return i;
            }
            return -1;
          }
        let indexofarray = `items.${array.indexOfObject("item",`${item.name}`)}.quantity`
        User.findOneAndUpdate({username:"username"},
            {
               $set:{
                indexofarray: array.item.quantity++
               }
            }).then(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
```

i want to increase the quantity of the given item in the array which is straight forward. But i dont know where the item is going to be in the array so I have to get it using a function. But i cant throw that in there because it doesn't take variable's or `item.${array.indexOfObject("item",`${item.name}`)}.quantity`. Is there a way to do this? Or a different way to achieve this result?

any help towards the right direction helps!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65619601/mongodb-update-with-arrayfilters-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer online that works!
simply, all you have to do is add brackets [] and then but a variable inside or in quotes like I did.

```js
$set: {
      [`item.${item}.quantity`]: quantity++
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to update item.quantity for a give item.name, where item is an array.

You can use [$[]](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#mongodb-update-up.---identifier--). No need to find the index first.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
{username: "username"},
{
    $inc:{"item.$[elem].quantity": 1}
},
{arrayFilters: [{"elem.name": "value"}]}
)
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P_8CWD1-mEf)

Comment: What if I don’t know the item name and I need to use a variable?

Comment: I dont know the exact mongoose syntax, but you can use the variable in place of `"value"`.

Comment: Yeah that’s not what I want I wanted to specify the element I’m changing because it’s the user getting one more from a crate